# Blur effect while drawing with Quartz 2D

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, core-graphics, quartz-graphics

I'd like to have a blur effect while drawing like the right line in this picture:

[image: Blur effect]

Currently, I'm drawing with the following code, but this only draws the picture on the left:

```
CGContextSetLineWidth(currentContext, thickness);    
CGContextSetLineCap(currentContext, kCGLineCapRound);
CGContextBeginPath(currentContext);
CGContextMoveToPoint(currentContext, x, y);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(currentContext, x, y);
CGContextMoveToPoint(currentContext, x, y);
CGContextStrokePath(currentContext);
```

Any ideas for me please?

Regards,
Alexandre

Answer (score 2):

```
CIContext *context = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];
CIImage *inputImage = [[CIImage alloc] initWithImage:@"your image"];
CIFilter *filter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIGaussianBlur"];
[filter setValue:inputImage forKey:kCIInputImageKey];
[filter setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:9.0f] forKey:@"inputRadius"];
CIImage *result = [filter valueForKey:kCIOutputImageKey];
CGImageRef cgImage = [context createCGImage:result fromRect:[result extent]];
UIImage *blurrImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgImage];
```

use this code this will give you blurr effect.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but 'd like to draw with the blur effect, not applying an effect on a UIImage.

Comment: after you draw, render that in a CIImage. `imageWithCGImage:` if you need it.

Comment: You may want to use `fromRect:[inputImage extent]` instead. This could ensure `blurrImage` is of same size as `inputImage`. Use `[result extent]` could lead to image size shrinking.